# Automate Letsencrypt SSL Certificate installation with PHP shell_exec command via acme.sh snap package

Tags: php, ssl, lets-encrypt, shell-exec, acme.sh

I install lets encrypt certificates through acme.sh snap package

https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh

I am wondering if there is any way to automate certificate installation via PHP default shell_exec() command.

This shell command used to get certificates works just fine when logged in via SSH

> acme.sh --issue --dns dns_gd -d example.com -d *.example.com

However, if I call the same command via PHP shell_exec, it always throws an error

```
$domainName = 'example.com';
$initCommand = "acme.sh --issue --dns dns_gd -d $domainName -d *.$domainName";
$output = shell_exec("$initCommand 2>&1 | tee -a /var/www/html/sshout.txt 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &");
```

sshout.txt - The output I am getting on sshout is as following

```
ssh: 1: /home/ubuntu/.acme.sh: Permission denied
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Is it possible to get certificates this way?

Or any other way to automate it via  PHP? by setting cron, or creating a bash script and calling it from PHP?

I am running PHP 7.2 on ubuntu 18 on an apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You should have permission and the right path to run the bash script. I guess this topic is what you need [PHP script can't run bash script. sh: Permission denied](https://superuser.com/questions/455935/php-script-cant-run-bash-script-sh-permission-denied)

the other way is using [acmephp](https://acmephp.github.io/)